# PHP / MySQL foreach not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, cs-cart

I'm rather new to PHP / MySQL and the addon I'm trying to fix on cs-cart software keeps failing.

PHP in question:

```
$acId = $_REQUEST['id'];

$productsGet = db_get_field("SELECT cart FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?i", $acId);
fn_print_die($productsGet);
$products = unserialize($productsGet);

$shippingCost = db_get_field("SELECT shipping FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
$tax = db_get_field("SELECT tax FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
$orderTotal = db_get_field("SELECT order_total FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);
$email = db_get_field("SELECT email FROM ?:abandoned_cart WHERE user_id = ?s", $acId);

$sum=0;
//echo $products;
if (!empty($products)) {
  foreach($products as $product){
    $text .='
      <tr>
        <td><a  href="http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'?dispatch=products.view&product_id='.$product['product_id'].'"> <img title="" height="120" width="120" alt="" src="'.$product['main_pair']['detailed']['image_path'].'"></a></td>
        <td><a href="#" style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['product'].'</a><a href="#">&nbsp;<i></i></a><div style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;"> CODE: <span>'.$product['product_code'].'<!--product_code_update_2512012004--></span> </div></td>
        <td style=" text-align:center;"><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">$</span><span style=" font-weight:bold; color:#333; font-size:12px; margin-top:4px; text-decoration:none;">'.$product['price'].'</span> </td>
        <td><div style="display: inline-block;vertical-align: top;width: 56px;"><input type="text" disabled value="'.$product['amount'].'" size="3"  style="border:1px solid #c2c9d0; box-shadow:0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset; border-radius:3px; float: left;height: 33px;text-align: center;width: 36px;"></div></td>
        <td style="font-size:14px;  font-weight:bold; color:#333; text-align:center; font-size:13px; text-decoration:none;"><span>$</span><span stye=" color:#000;">'.$product['price']*$product['amount'].'</span> </td>
      </tr>';
    $sum =$sum+$product['price']*$product['amount'];
  }
}
```

response from fn_print_die($productGet);

```
"a:1:{i:598710622;a:24:{s:10:\"product_id\";i:511;s:12:\"product_code\";s:4:\"3021\";s:7:\"product\";s:33:\"Avatar Lounger - Wildberry Deluxe\";s:6:\"amount\";i:1;s:15:\"product_options\";a:1:{i:365;s:3:\"731\";}s:5:\"price\";d:249;s:12:\"stored_price\";s:1:\"N\";s:9:\"main_pair\";a:5:{s:7:\"pair_id\";s:4:\"1027\";s:8:\"image_id\";s:1:\"0\";s:11:\"detailed_id\";s:4:\"2123\";s:8:\"position\";s:1:\"0\";s:8:\"detailed\";a:8:{s:10:\"image_path\";s:95:\"http://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg?t=1401991929\";s:3:\"alt\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"image_x\";s:4:\"1500\";s:7:\"image_y\";s:4:\"1500\";s:15:\"http_image_path\";s:95:\"http://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg?t=1401991929\";s:16:\"https_image_path\";s:96:\"https://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg?t=1401991929\";s:13:\"absolute_path\";s:90:\"/home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/images/detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg\";s:13:\"relative_path\";s:41:\"detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg\";}}s:5:\"extra\";a:2:{s:15:\"product_options\";a:1:{i:365;s:3:\"731\";}s:18:\"unlimited_download\";s:1:\"N\";}s:15:\"stored_discount\";s:1:\"N\";s:10:\"company_id\";s:1:\"1\";s:12:\"amount_total\";i:1;s:12:\"options_type\";s:1:\"P\";s:15:\"exceptions_type\";s:1:\"F\";s:15:\"modifiers_price\";d:0;s:6:\"is_edp\";s:1:\"N\";s:12:\"edp_shipping\";s:1:\"N\";s:8:\"discount\";i:0;s:10:\"promotions\";a:0:{}s:11:\"tax_summary\";a:3:{s:8:\"included\";d:22.6400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625;s:5:\"added\";i:0;s:5:\"total\";d:22.6400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625;}s:10:\"base_price\";d:249;s:12:\"category_ids\";a:1:{i:0;i:66;}s:13:\"display_price\";d:249;s:5:\"taxes\";a:1:{i:6;a:7:{s:9:\"rate_type\";s:1:\"P\";s:10:\"rate_value\";s:6:\"10.000\";s:18:\"price_includes_tax\";s:1:\"Y\";s:9:\"regnumber\";s:11:\"60499021423\";s:8:\"priority\";i:0;s:12:\"tax_subtotal\";d:22.6400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625;s:11:\"description\";s:3:\"GST\";}}}}"
```

As the above is from a function to debug; here is what's in the database field:

```
a:1:{i:598710622;a:24:{s:10:\"product_id\";i:511;s:12:\"product_code\";s:4:\"3021\";s:7:\"product\";s:33:\"Avatar Lounger - Wildberry Deluxe\";s:6:\"amount\";i:1;s:15:\"product_options\";a:1:{i:365;s:3:\"731\";}s:5:\"price\";d:249;s:12:\"stored_price\";s:1:\"N\";s:9:\"main_pair\";a:5:{s:7:\"pair_id\";s:4:\"1027\";s:8:\"image_id\";s:1:\"0\";s:11:\"detailed_id\";s:4:\"2123\";s:8:\"position\";s:1:\"0\";s:8:\"detailed\";a:8:{s:10:\"image_path\";s:95:\"http://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg?t=1401991929\";s:3:\"alt\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"image_x\";s:4:\"1500\";s:7:\"image_y\";s:4:\"1500\";s:15:\"http_image_path\";s:95:\"http://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg?t=1401991929\";s:16:\"https_image_path\";s:96:\"https://beanbags.ambientlounge.com/images/detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg?t=1401991929\";s:13:\"absolute_path\";s:90:\"/home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/images/detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg\";s:13:\"relative_path\";s:41:\"detailed/2/wildberry-deluxe-4_h85w-74.jpg\";}}s:5:\"extra\";a:2:{s:15:\"product_options\";a:1:{i:365;s:3:\"731\";}s:18:\"unlimited_download\";s:1:\"N\";}s:15:\"stored_discount\";s:1:\"N\";s:10:\"company_id\";s:1:\"1\";s:12:\"amount_total\";i:1;s:12:\"options_type\";s:1:\"P\";s:15:\"exceptions_type\";s:1:\"F\";s:15:\"modifiers_price\";d:0;s:6:\"is_edp\";s:1:\"N\";s:12:\"edp_shipping\";s:1:\"N\";s:8:\"discount\";i:0;s:10:\"promotions\";a:0:{}s:11:\"tax_summary\";a:3:{s:8:\"included\";d:22.6400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625;s:5:\"added\";i:0;s:5:\"total\";d:22.6400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625;}s:10:\"base_price\";d:249;s:12:\"category_ids\";a:1:{i:0;i:66;}s:13:\"display_price\";d:249;s:5:\"taxes\";a:1:{i:6;a:7:{s:9:\"rate_type\";s:1:\"P\";s:10:\"rate_value\";s:6:\"10.000\";s:18:\"price_includes_tax\";s:1:\"Y\";s:9:\"regnumber\";s:11:\"60499021423\";s:8:\"priority\";i:0;s:12:\"tax_subtotal\";d:22.6400000000000005684341886080801486968994140625;s:11:\"description\";s:3:\"GST\";}}}}
```

PHP error in console:

> **Fatal error**:  ob_get_clean() [<a href='ref.outcontrol'>ref.outcontrol</a>]: Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in **/home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/app/Tygh/Ajax.php** on line **131**

PHP error log:

> [Mon Feb 08 01:44:59 2016] [error] [client 90.199.142.58] PHP Fatal
>   error:  ob_get_clean() [ref.outcontrol]:
>   Cannot use output buffering in output buffering display handlers in
>   /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/app/Tygh/Ajax.php on line
>   131, referer: /admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list [Mon Feb 08 01:44:59
>   2016] [error] [client 90.199.142.58] PHP Fatal error:  Unsupported
>   operand types in
>   /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/app/Tygh/Database.php on
>   line 632, referer: /admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list [Mon Feb 08
>   01:44:59 2016] [error] [client 90.199.142.58] PHP Notice: 
>   unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset
>   23 of 2060 bytes in
>   /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/app/addons/abandoned_cart_extended/controllers/backend/ac.php
>   on line 24, referer: /admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list

I think the error in console and also first 2 in log can be ignore if I'm not mistaken, but focus is on

> Notice: unserialize() [function.unserialize]: Error at offset 23 of 2060 bytes in /home/ambcom/public_html/staging/beanbags/app/addons/abandoned_cart_extended/controllers/backend/ac.php on line 24, referer: /admin.php?dispatch=cart.cart_list

this is line:

```
$products = unserialize($productsGet);
```

Now I seem to be pulling cart the cart data from the query ok. But it's not just liking it's at the unserialize part and then to the loop.

The data returned from the query is exactly like it is in the database on the column "cart" so maybe the PHP is trying to handle it wrong? The a:1 part.

Comment: By copy/pasting your string exactly as posted here, I can `unserialize()` it successfully.

Comment: I checked the length of the string you posted via `mb_strlen()` and it is 1904. Can you verify that the string in the database is the same length? If it contained some non-printable characters they could interfere with unserialize.

Comment: Let me grab the exact data that is in the database field, 2 sec

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SdaFKC4M - this is what is in the database field

Comment: Hey man,  the code you posted is so messy that I can't figure how in the world does anybody can help you?  First things first: Place a clear an concise question, paste clear and READABLE code, then by the hand of god, somebody can help you.

Comment: I have given when i have... that is just whats returned from database and i need to take and i guess unserialize makes an array so the foreach works... i checked on here: http://unserialize.onlinephpfunctions.com/ and get offset error as well, not sure how to handle the data received... but ive given and provided as much as i can.

Comment: When I unserialize that string by pasting it into my REPL console with `php -a` it works. When I place it into a file it does not, and furthermore, the cursor is dropped down to the next line. I suspect there may be a rogue `CR` or similar character in there. Inspect it with a hex editor, especially at position 23.

Comment: Ok so should work? as i say this is all new to me and at a roadblock so im not going crazy then? i dont know what to do and also what you suggested threw me lol